# Where is 'Data' option for charts

Tags: excel

I have a chart that sits in an excel file - I need to access the 'Data' option from right clicking on the chart and going to 'Format'. For example, I right click on the chart -> Click 'Format' -> Right side pane should show 'Format' AND 'Data', however, for me, it's only showing 'Format' as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I need to be able to access 'Data' as well. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can include 'Data' from this Chart pane, or do I need to enable it somewhere? I searched online and cannot find anything in regard to the chart pane with the 'Data' option.

I have a colleague that shows 'Format' and 'Data' but they're unsure as to why mine is not showing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All the elements of a table have their own sub-menu. When hovering over the elements (each in a different area's of the frame that your table is using) you could try clicking the right mouse button and see which options you are given. "Data" is not needed for all elements of the table.

Or could it be security settings?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was thinking it could be a security setting. Will be getting someone to look into it. Thanks again for your response!